# How to make a gallery "off-center" in Android

Tags: android, gallery, padding

Actually i got a Gallery that shows my drawables and shows the item selected on the center of the screen.

I would like my selected item to be "off-center" (e.g: positioned 50dip on the left).

I tried to add some padding on the view and on the gallery. I also verified that the gravity of my gallery wasn't set in "center"

By the way, I guess that the usual behaviour of the gallery is to show selected item on the center of the screen.

Is there any possible means to shift the position of the selected item ?

Thanks a lot ! If needed, I can add my code.

Comment: I think you should explore the source  code of the Gallery to see how it's done and mabe it will give you some clues...

Comment: Ok as you said answer is simple :

Add 50dip to Scroll X parameter on the gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer finally.

First, you have to set ScrollX to a certain value corresponding to the interval of pixels you wanna have.

But the problem with that only solution is that to select an item, you need to click on the center of the screen, which isn't fair.

Second, you must override Gallery, implement this one OnDoubleTapListener and add him a custom listener (called for instance onItemTapListener) like this :

```
public void setOnTapItemMenuListener(OnTapItemMenuListener listener) {
     onTapItemMenuListener = listener;
}
```

I made an interface like this to implement my new listener :

```
public interface OnTapItemMenuListener {
    public abstract void onTap(int intPosition);
}
```

And on the event "onSingleTapConfirmed" implemented because of the implementation of OnDoubleTapListener, you catch the event and verify that event.getX() is into a certain position, like this for instance :

```
if (event.getX() / intWidth > 0.20f && event.getX() / intWidth < 0.45f) {
     Log.i("TAG", "onSingleTapConfirmed on the right area, we launch onTap for the Listener");
     onTapItemMenuListener.onTap(this.getSelectedItemPosition());
} else {
     Log.i("TAG", "onSingleTapConfirmed on the wrong area, we don't launch onTap for the Listener");
}
```

Where intWidth is the width in pixels of the current screen.